# Connection is success, when client sent data not reached to server but client disconnects data sent to server

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

Here i put some code, connection establish but whenever client wants to sent some data to server data not sent if client dis-connect data as soon as reaches to server how to fix that problem.

what i want :
if connection establish and connection not close.

```
public class Server extends AppCompatActivity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
Handler UIHandler;
Thread Thread1 = null;
EditText edText;
public static final int SERVERPORT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Server");
    edText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    UIHandler = new Handler();
    this.Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
    this.Thread1.start();

}

class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    InetAddress addr;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(getLocalIpAddress());
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                Thread2 commThread = new Thread2(socket);

                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getLocalIpAddress() throws Exception {
    String resultIpv6 = "";
    String resultIpv4 = "";

    for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
         en.hasMoreElements(); ) {

        NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
             enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {

            InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    resultIpv4 = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                } else if (inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address) {
                    resultIpv6 = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ((resultIpv4.length() > 0) ? resultIpv4 : resultIpv6);
}

private class Thread2 implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedReader input;
    String read;

    public Thread2(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                read = this.input.readLine();

                if (read != null) {

                    Server.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edText.setText(edText.getText().toString() + "Client says: " + read + "\n");
                            Log.i("hhFULL", edText.getText().toString());
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                    Thread1.start();
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no client code here. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Here for testing purpose i'm using TCP Client is Hercules utility(s/w).   Dear @EJP, yes it is server code when any client(s/w) is connected to that server connection is establish but when client send some text to server not reaches until client disconnects connection.

Comment: So post the client code. You can't just arbitrarily decide that the problem must be in the server code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because the client you're using is sending a message without a \n or \r in the end. Below code that reads a line from inputStream waits for a newline character infinitely:-

```
read = this.input.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solve when client sent some data, it needs ( ASCII code) new line.